# If + should vs. if + would

Tags: conditional-constructions, will-would, if

> In certain clauses, **should** is used for all three persons:
>
> > *If I/you/he **should** decide to go, we will need a larger car*. *If it **should** begin to snow, we will stay here tonight*.
>
> **Would** is not acceptable in
> these **if clauses**, but it does appear in other kinds of **conditional
> clauses**:
>
> > *He might surprise you if you **would** give him a chance*
>
> https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=should

What are those "if-clauses" in which *would* is not acceptable but **should** is?

What are those "other kinds of conditional clauses" in which *would* is acceptable?

Comment: Just a comment: This use of *should* is very rare in colloquial American English, and sounds formal (or foreign) to an American. (I would probably use *were to* in place of *should* in your examples)

Comment: It's a bit old-fashioned in British English, but there are still plenty of people who use it.

Comment: We can use the modal auxiliary verb 'would' in 'if-clauses' when expressing the conditional mood (the action is possible but uncertain and depends on a condition). The modal auxiliary verb can also be used in if-clause in subjunctive mood (the action/outcome is not possible). The term would is not used in any other case apart from conditional and subjunctive mood.

Answer (score 1):

In these conditional clauses ***would*** is not an auxilairy but a verb in itself pointing to the willingness of someone to do something:

> ***Will*** and ***would*** can be used in conditional clauses, either with the meaning of ‘***being willing to do something***’, or *to refer to later results*:
>
> - If Clare *will* meet us at the airport, it will save us a lot of time. (if Clare is willing to meet us)
> - If you ***would*** all stop shouting, I will try and explain the situation!
>
> We sometimes ***stress*** the *will* or *would*, especially if we doubt that the result will be the one mentioned:
>
> - If it really would save the planet, I’d stop using my car tomorrow. (If it really is true that the planet would be saved as a result, I would stop using my car, but I doubt it is true.) ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-if))

As for the if-clauses that do not accept ***would*** but ***should***, it is when we

> refer to events which might happen by chance or by accident:
>
> - If you should bump into Carol, can you tell her I’m looking for her? (If by chance you bump into Carol.)

Note that these if-clauses that can take ***should*** are first conditionals, which is why ***would*** cannot be acceptable (as an auxiliary). Here *should* could be replaced by *In the eventuality that/if it happens that/in case*:

> ***In case it begins*** to snow, we will stay here tonight.

Used as an auxiliary, ***would*** in the second and third conditionals triggers the use of past tense or past perfect in the if-clause. In a first conditional, *would* can only be used in the if-clause as a main verb as I explained in the beginning.

Basically you can have both ***should*** (as an auxilary) and ***would*** (as a main verb) in first conditionals, but these are very different uses from the point of both grammar and meaning. Consider:

> - If you ***should*** decide to go, we will need a larger car. *[In case you change your mind and decide to go]*
> - If you ***would*** go, I am not against it. *[If you are willing to go, you can, I will allow it]*

Comment: Those "if-clauses" in which **would** is not acceptable are where _should_ is